# Adding Event Kit.Framework results in 1000+ Errors When Deployed to Device!

Tags: iphone, eventkit

I need to add a calendar event to the user's Calendar when they click a button.

This works in the simulator, but when I attempt to deploy to my 3GS running iOS 4.01, XCODE throws 1000+ errors!

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Jason

Answer (score 0):

I think that I solved this.

In Project > Edit Project Settings under the Architecture, I had the Base SDK set to iPhone 3.2.  When I changed it to iPhone 4.0, it compiled and deployed to my iPhone 3GS running iOS 4.

I think that this is due to Event Kit being something that was added in iOS 4 and not available in earlier versions.

I was planning to target earlier devices.  So, I guess it's back to the drawing board to come up with a solution to adding a reminder/event to the user's calendar.

Jason

Comment: I am still having trouble with this.  Now, when I try to run this in the simulator I get a 75+ errors!